# How to dynamically import CKEditor in Vue.js 3 only on client-side?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to include `CKEditor 5` in my Vue.js 3 app but am struggling with including it **only** on client-side. I am using server-side rendering which cannot handle `window` that CKEditor uses, so it must only load only if the browser requests it, and not Node.js.

In the setup() method I can test for `IsBrowser` like this:

```
const IsBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
```

How can I perform `import` and initialise a component only if `IsBrowser` is true?

I have to do the following code to make CKEditor-5 work:

```
    <CKEditor v-if="IsBrowser" id="PostContent" class="ck-content" contenteditable="true" :editor="CKEditorInline" ></CKEditor>
```

```
<script>
    import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/dist/ckeditor'
    import CKEditorInline from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-inline/src/inlineeditor';
    
    export default {
    
      name: "ComponentCreate",
      components: {
        CKEditor: CKEditor.component
      }, 
    data() {
    return {
      CKEditorInline: CKEditorInline,
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TLDR

Working solution (explanation is below):

```html
<CKEditor v-if="IsBrowser && CKEditorInline"
  id="PostContent"
  class="ck-content"
  contenteditable="true"
  :editor="CKEditorInline"
></CKEditor>
```

```js
<script>
import { ref, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: "ComponentCreate",
  components: {
    CKEditor: defineAsyncComponent(() => {
      return import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/dist/ckeditor')
      .then(module => module.component)
    })
  },
  setup() {
    const IsBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
    let CKEditorInline = ref(null);

    if (IsBrowser) {
      import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-inline/src/inlineeditor')
      .then(e => CKEditorInline.value = e.default)
    }

    return { IsBrowser, CKEditorInline }
  },
};
</script>
```

---

There are two challenges here:

1. Conditionally load the `<CKEditor>` *component*
2. Conditionally load the `CKEditorInline` *module*'s export

#### Conditionally Load `<CKEditor>` component

Use [`defineAsyncComponent`](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#_3-x-syntax) to lazy load and register the component.  It only loads and registers if the template actually renders it.  So only when the `v-if` is true.

```js
components: {
  CKEditor: defineAsyncComponent(() => {
    return import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/dist/ckeditor')
    .then(module => module.component)
  })
},
```

<sup>Extra challenge, not the module but the `component` property is needed in your case</sup>

#### Conditionally load `CKEditorInline` module export

For this dynamic module, we want the default export

```js
let CKEditorInline = ref(null);
if (IsBrowser) {
  import('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-inline/src/inlineeditor')
  .then(e => CKEditorInline.value = e.default)
}
```

#### Change the `v-if` condition

```html
<CKEditor v-if="IsBrowser && CKEditorInline" :editor="CKEditorInline"></CKEditor>
```

Comment: Absolutely superb! Can I do multiple imports using `import('@ckeditor....')` because I also need to import options to configure CKEditor like `import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';` and `import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';`.

Comment: Yeah you can just load each one inside the `if` block and set different `ref` values, in the same way as `CKEditorInline`

Comment: This works well but when I refresh the page (causing SSR to deliver the page), the client-side hydration never kicks in so the CKEditor component does not load at all. Shouldn't Vue take over the page and then load the component?

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the SSR to provide the pre-rendered page (including the editor)?  I don't have a guess for why that would happen unless the `setup` isn't being run at all